# Can't load ICON resource in VC++ 2012 Ultimate

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I am having problem adding icon resource to C++ Win32 Project. I followed the steps in pictures down under but we I run program.exe there is no my icon in menu bar (only default icon). *.exe file has new icon as it should.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    LPCWSTR className = L"MyWindow";
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = className;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_ICON1));
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,L"Error, registration of class faild", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your window style is 0.

Try:

```
wc.style         = WS_SYSMENU;
```

Comment: now it fails to create window error message after hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, className, L"Window Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,300,200,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

Comment: before Create Window fails to register

Answer (score 0):

wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));

Comment: This question has been posted and got an answer accepted more than years ago. Please avoid digging such old post if already answered